# Prove that if $∀b>1$, $x,y>0$ and $x/y<b$ then $x \leq y$

Tags: calculus

Prove: if
$$
\forall \space b > 1 \space\space \space  x,y >0  \space   \space \text{and}  \space x/y < b
$$
then $x$ and $y$ satisfy the relation:
$$
x \leq y
$$
I understand the idea that $x$ has to be less than $y$ so the result is between $0$ and $1$ but I don't know how to express it with symbols.

Comment: Do you by chance mean $b<1$?

Comment: No, it's $b$ $>$ $1$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the $\forall$

Comment: If it holds for all $b<1$. Then we get $x/y\leq 1$ and hence $x\leq y$.

Comment: It is for all   $b$ $>$ $1$ , NOT $b$ $<$ $1$. This is exactly why I find difficult the problem. The problem is in a chapter related to the supremum and infimum concepts.

Comment: @gary Why did you deleted your comment about 1 + $\epsilon$ ? I was just starting to think about it and it dissapeared.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 The answer by TurlocTheRed goes along that line, you just have to understand it. I recommend you to study/revise a bit of elementary maths logic and basics of arithmetic of the real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x>y$. Then $x/y>1$. But this contradicts $x/y<b$ for choice of $b=1+1/n$ where we choose integer $n$ so that $1/n<x/y-1$. So we have a contradiction for $x>y$. By the trichotomy property, That only leaves $x=y$ or $x<y$.

We know such an $n$ exists, because by the Archimedean property of the reals there is an $n$, $\frac{y}{x-y}<n$.

Comment: Why 1/n<x/y−1 is contradictory? if x/y > 1 then x/y  can be 1.00000001, and this less 1 is 0.00000001 and 1/n can be less than that.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 Look at how $n$ was chosen.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x > y$, then $b := \frac xy > 1$, thus $x < by$, i.e. $x < \frac xyy = x$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: what does the symbol := means?

Comment: it defines $b$ as $\frac xy$

Comment: But b can be irrational, can a x/y generate any irrational?

Comment: the opposite of "for every $b$ such that fact is true" is "there exists a $b$ such that fact si false"

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

b $\in$ $(1, \infty)$

Then

$x/y < b \space => 1$ is supremum (it can be proved if necessary) of the set composed of $x/y$.

It follows that $x/y < 1$, hence $x < y$.